# Как с помощью Logstash отправить access-лог Nginx в Elasticsearch?

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, devops, logstash, kibana

Доброго времени суток!

Мне нужно с помощью Logstash отправить access-лог Nginx в Elasticsearch. Для визуализации данных Elasticsearch использую Kibana.

Конфигурационный файл nginx.conf у меня имеет следующий вид:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  logstash  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  logstash;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Конфигурационный файл elasticsearch.yml:

```
---
cluster.name: elk
node.name: node-1
node.roles:
  - master
  - data
  - ingest
cluster.initial_master_nodes:
  - node-1
discovery.seed_hosts:
  - localhost
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Конфигурационный файл logstash.yml:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/nginx/access.log"
    start_position => "begining"
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:remote_ip} - %{DATA:user_name}
    \[%{HTTPDATE:access_time}\] \"%{WORD:http_method} %{DATA:url}
    HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version}\" %{NUMBER:response_code} %{NUMBER:body_sent_bytes}
    \"%{DATA:referrer}\" \"%{DATA:agent}\"" }
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "host" ]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "https://localhost:9200"
    data_stream => "true"
  }
}
```

В моем представлении, все должно работать и логи Nginx должны отображаться в интерфейсе kibana, но по факту на странице kibana, в разделе discover у меня ничего нет.
[image: Скриншот 1]

Все сервисы, а именно Elasticsearch, Kibana, Logstash и Nginx - установлен на одном хосте.
Подозреваю, что все дело в не правильном конфигурационном файле Nginx.conf, но что именно не  так разобраться не получается.
Пожалуйста, подскажите как решить проблему?